# Proof verification: Dimension of the subspace of solutions for $\mathbf{Ax}=0$ equals $n-rk(A)$, where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw the following statement in an open [book](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf) about machine learning:

> For $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ the subspace of solutions for $\mathbf{Ax} = 0$ possesses dimension $n − rk(\mathbf{A})$. Later, we will call this subspace the kernel or the null space.

Where $rk(\mathbf{A})$ denotes the rank of matrix $\mathbf{A}$. I know the definition of "the space solution" but I haven't heard of the term "subspace of solutions". So my understanding here is that it's the same as the solution space but viewed as a subspace of another vector space.

Given that I can see that this statement is another way of phrasing the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps. Because if we let $T:\ V \to W$ be the linear map corresponding to the matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, then from the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
dim\ V &= dim\ null\ T + dim\ range\ T\\
n &= dim\ null\ T + rank\ \mathbf{A}\\
dim\ null\ T &= n - rank\ \mathbf{A}.
\end{align}
$$

Is there anything wrong with the above proof?

Comment: That is not the fundamental theorem of algebra. It's called the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: No, that's not, my typo. I mean "the fundamental of Linear Maps" or rank-nullity theorem as you mentioned.

Comment: did you perhaps meant solution space? I've never heard of the term "space solution" before.

In any case, I don't see much wrong with your "proof".

Comment: @David it's solution space, My another typo I've fixed it.